# Correct tense for "I wish I had more time so i could've baked some cookies"

Tags: verbs, tenses, past-tense

Whats the correct way of saying this?

- I wish I had more time so i could've baked some cookies
- I wish I've had more time so i could've baked some cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question is in scope for this site but...

Neither of those is correct.

You could say: I wish I'd had more time so I could've baked more cookies.

Comment: Thanks! I'd is a contraction to had?

Comment: *I'd* can be a contract of *I would*, but in Dave's sentence it is a contraction of *I had*.